# how to remove an element from a list of user define class?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am fairly new to c#, please be gentle to me, I have been searching through the net for a few hours without success, I want to remove an element from my user defined class. How do I do it?

below is the snippet of the code.

```
public class Level2
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public long volume { get; set; }

    public Level2(double price, long volume)
    {
        this.price = price;
        this.volume = volume;
    }
}

static void Main()
{

    List<Level2> bid = new List<Level2>();

    ask.Add(new Level2(200, 500));
    ask.Add(new Level2(300, 400));
    ask.Add(new Level2(300, 600));


    // how to remove this element ???
    ask.Remove(300, 400);       //doesn't work

 }
```

I think I need to implement IEnumerable of some sort, but how does the syntax look like? can someone please give me a working snippet? thanks a lot

Comment: What is the relation between `ask` and `bid`? Are they supposed to be the same variable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will remove all `Level2` objects with **`Price = 300 and Volume = 400`** from the list

```
ask.RemoveAll(a => a.price == 300 && a.volume == 400);
```

Comment: glad I could help; if it answered your question you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd do it: override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `Level2`, so that you can use `List<T>.Remove` without needing the original reference to the object.

```
public class Level2
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public long volume { get; set; }

    public Level2(double price, long volume)
    {
        this.price = price;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Level2;
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return other.price == this.price && other.volume == this.volume;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return price.GetHashCode() ^ volume.GetHashCode();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Level2> ask = new List<Level2>();

    ask.Add(new Level2(200, 500));
    ask.Add(new Level2(300, 400));
    ask.Add(new Level2(300, 600));

    ask.Remove(new Level2(300, 400));
}
```

Here's another way, which works off of the identity of the object instead of the values inside of it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Level2> ask = new List<Level2>();

    ask.Add(new Level2(200, 500));
    var level = new Level2(300, 400);
    ask.Add(level);
    ask.Add(new Level2(300, 600));

    ask.Remove(level);
}
```

Depending on your situation, one of these, or one of the other answers, may be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you are adding instantiated `objects` to the typed List **bid**, so you'll need to search your list for objects to remove that match a certain condition. Note that you could have multiple (different) instances of `Level2` in your list with `price==300` and `volume==400`.

A small code sample should clarify things.

```
public class Level2
{
    public double price { get; set; }
    public long volume { get; set; }
    public Level2(double price, long volume)
    {
        this.price = price;
        this.volume = volume;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Level 2 object with price: {0} and volume: {1}", 
            this.price, this.volume);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<Level2> bid = new List<Level2>();
    bid.Add(new Level2(200, 500));
    bid.Add(new Level2(300, 400));
    bid.Add(new Level2(300, 600));
    bid.Add(new Level2(300, 400)); // second item with these quantities

    List<Level2> toRemove = 
        bid.Where(x => x.price == 300 && x.volume == 400).ToList<Level2>();

    foreach (Level2 item in toRemove)
    {
        bid.Remove(item);
        Console.WriteLine("removing " + item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but are you sure? I mean removing an item from the list where you are iterating on?

Comment: @Steve: you are right, I already updated my answer since that was asking for trouble ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first retrieve the element you want to remove:

```
Level2 element = ask.FirstOrDefault(l => l.price == 300 && l.volume == 400);
if (element != null)
    ask.Remove(element);
```