# remove a custom object from list c#

Tags: c#

I have this code

```
Class location
{
     int X{Get; Set;}
     int Y{Get;Set;}
}

List<location> mylst = new List<location>();
Public Void SetupList()
{
    for(int i =0; i<8; i++)
    {
       for(int b=0; b<8; b++)
       {
         location loc = new location();
         loc.x = b;
         loc.y = i;
          mylst.Add(loc);
       }
    }
}
```

Once the list is populated i want to be able to search through the list and see if any of the items in the list contain a location i.e

```
/// lets search for location 4,4
location tofind = new location()
tofind.x=4;
tofind.y=4;
foreach(location loc in mylst)
{
   if(loc == tofind)
   {
       ///delete that item from the list  

   }
}
```

but i am at a total loss on how to do this...

Any ideas would be helpful as nothing i have tried has worked

Comment: Override the `==` operator or the `Equals()` function (and use it), right now you're checking for pointer equality.

Comment: and how do i override it? im new to lists

Comment: You might want to put in some effort to make the code you post actually compile...

Comment: the code is snippet from that it can be worked out i am trying to do

Comment: @ Patrick and where exactly is this duplicate?? rather than just marking it why not inform me of where this is and i would gladly look at it and then see if it is what i am after

Comment: I have taken the liberty to un-mark this as a duplicate. Overriding Equals is *one way* to solve the OPs problem, but not the only one. In general, I don't consider "How do I implement <one possible solution to problem X>?" to be a duplicate for "How do I solve problem X?".

Comment: @MarkW: The duplicate link can be found at the top of your question. Or rather... it *could* be found, because I just un-marked your question as a duplicate. In general, however, Patrick is right: *If* you question is a duplicate, closing it as a duplicate is the right thing to do.

Comment: exactly Heinzi and what you have actually posted is what i needed exactly

Comment: Better duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/10870131/993547

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yep, good find! Feel free to close, I won't object.

Comment: You know I already used my vote. You on the other hand have one left. Feel free ;) @heinzi

Comment: @Heinzi i noticed the duplicate notice above however that solution was far too complex for what i needed to do yours fits exact

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Oh, didn't know that the vote stays "in use" after reopening. Closed.

Comment: Patrick i agree i didnt seem to find that one when searching

Comment: Yeah, to prevent close wars I guess.

Comment: @MarkW: Glad I could help! The new duplicate should be better, it has examples for both options 1 and 2 of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. [Override Equals/== and GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567642/how-to-best-implement-equals-for-custom-types). That way, `loc == tofind` will yield true when the *values* of the two instances match.
2. Search by explicitly comparing values:

   ```
   var listFound = myList.Where(loc => loc.X == tofind.X && loc.Y == tofind.Y).ToList();
   ```